# If a buy a mac from another retailer, do I get the same warranty that I would get from Apple?

Tags: mac, apple-inc, warranty, applecare

On [this page](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC246LL/B?mco=MTY3ODQ5OTY), it shows that without the Apple Care package, you get 1 year [limited warranty](http://www.apple.com/legal/warranty/), and 90 days of [complimentary telephone technical support](http://www.apple.com/support/complimentary/) on a mac.

If I buy the mac from another retailer (e.g. Amazon), would I still get these same benefits?

Comment: The answers of "you get the same warranty from other retailers" are correct *unless* you buy your Mac on the gray market. I don't know how prevalent it is today, but for a while you could buy refurbished Macs from non-authorized retailers and you actually had no warranty. (Note that Apple sells their own refurbished machines sometimes, and they have full warranties; the warranty's existence is dependent upon the authorization status of the retailer.)

Comment: @Matthew: Is there any way to check the authorization status of a dealer? I noticed that on Amazon, many of the macs say that they you are purchasing it from some other retailer, not directly from Amazon. The product details is limited and doesn't mention much about the product itself, much less about a warranty.

Comment: This list seems to be authoritative: http://solutionprofessionals.apple.com/catalog/ It's probably worth checking the various categories on the left if you're looking for someone, in case they don't happen to fall into the category I linked to.

Comment: @Matthew: Thanks for the link, it really helped. Could you please post that as an answer so that I can accept it? I think it's the most correct answer since you can't blindly assume that any mac you buy online will have Apple's warranty. It seems that you must make sure that you are buying from an Apple authorized reseller.

Comment: I added it, glad to help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll get the same warranty from an *authorized* Apple retailer as you would from Apple directly. I don't know how prevalent it is today, but for a while you could buy refurbished Macs from non-authorized retailers and you ended up with little or no warranty. (Note that Apple sometimes sells refurbished machines that do have full warranties; the warranty's existence is dependent upon the authorization status of the retailer.)

Apple provides a way to determine which retailers are authorized on the **[Solution Professionals portion of their website](http://solutionprofessionals.apple.com/catalog/)**. Be sure to check that list before making a purchase.

Answer (score 1):

Every new Mac comes with 1 year of AppleCare.  The option is to extend that AppleCare up to 3 years.  And, I believe you can do this at any time, IF the Mac is STILL covered by your original 1-year.  As in - I believe you can buy 2 extra years right before your 1 year (that it came with) is up.

With regards to a warranty done by "in house" staff (IE - FutureShop or BestBuy selling you one of "their" warranties, which are supposed to be better), it's usually not worth it.  They usually end up sending your stuff off to Apple to fix, so you just wait longer.

Answer (score 1):

One of the big problems you often see when purchasing from a non-authorized dealer, is they'll strip the extras that Apple bundles with the machine, and sell those separately.

There's a place near me that does that; Go to buy a replacement power-supply and they will have taken out the cord and wall-outlet adapter, and put those in separate bags, forcing people to buy them separately.

Apple's prices are reasonable, as are the prices from Best-Buy or other authorized dealers, and to avoid any BS like those other places I stick with the real-deal.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The warranty is on the product it does not depend the retailer.

You can extend the AppleCare warranty from 1 to 3 years within the first year of its life.

Answer (score 0):

In the UK if you buy your Mac from John Lewis you get a 2 year warranty, but TBH the Apple warranty is really effective, it's great being able to walk into an Apple store and have them fix it while you wait.